# How to verify a htpasswd-generated bcrypt hash using PHP?

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt, .htpasswd

I have to verify bcrypt-hashes created by apache's `htpasswd` tool (v2.4.41) using PHP's `password_verify` (v7.4.3).

But if I generate a hash:

```
$ htpasswd -nbB test pass
test:$2y$05$m73wHlBS62EUh7uAxbUCJ.gHIfcEgiorl/1LrzNRAlSSH4bmrBUEy
```

... and then try to verify it in PHP ...

```
cat << EOF | php -a
if (password_verify('pass', '$2y$05$m73wHlBS62EUh7uAxbUCJ.gHIfcEgiorl/1LrzNRAlSSH4bmrBUEy')) {
  echo 'match';
} else {
  echo 'mismatch';
}
EOF
```

... `mismatch` is printed. PHP can however verify its own bcrypt hashes ...

```
cat << EOF | php -a
if (password_verify('test', password_hash('test', PASSWORD_BCRYPT))) {
  echo 'match';
} else {
  echo 'mismatch';
}
EOF
```

... this prints `match`. How can I get `password_verify` to verify the externally generated bcrypt hash?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I get "match" when testing that hash: https://3v4l.org/fDC3h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my real-world code there was additional whitespace at the end of the hash due incorrect parsing of the hash value out of a `.htpasswd` file.

The 'simplified' example in the OP introduced another, different problem (due escaping special characters in the hash on the commandline) and failed because of that.

Comment: That's why your question should include your actual code. Glad you found your answer.